# Yahoo! Messenger messages don't appear on IM window after doing a Process Explorer+Autoruns cleanup

Tags: yahoo-messenger

My wife's laptop was plagued with various malware so after doing an anti-virus run, I used Sysinternals Process Explorer and Autoruns utilities to find windows startup calls and other trash calls entered by the malware.

Problem is after doing all these, Yahoo Messenger stopped displaying messages in the IM window. Neither my messages nor the messages of any contact is showing up in the window, although my contacts are saying that they can see my messages on their end. Their messages also still show up at the popup-alerts.

I've tried reinstalling Yahoo Messenger 10 several times. I also tried installing Yahoo Messenger 11 but that didn't work too. I tried reinstalling all the requisites specified here: http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_MSNG&id=DOC249&impressions=false but no luck either.

Anybody have a clue on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think with all these problem it is safe to say that the machine should be reinstalled from ground up rather than being fixed.. some malware may be intercepting calls and spy on your message (I don't know) but i guess the easy fix is not to fix the computer but rather backup, formatting and reinstalling everything. that could save you hours...

Comment: I am almost conceded that this will be the case, but I hoped it isn't that bad, considering it's "only" YM.